# Order by count(name) AND printing it

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm printing determined rows based on a date range. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, count(ID)
FROM Products
WHERE Date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2'
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY count(ID)
LIMIT 10
```

And it works, but my question is: How do I **print** the "count" value? I haven't found anything yet, but I'm a bad searcher anyway.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, count(ID) as TOTAL
```

now look for total as you looked for ID.

Comment: That easy? Wow, I'm really dumb after all. It works. Thanks a lot; as soon as the 9 minutes pases, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Give it an alias.

```
... COUNT(`id`) AS cnt ...
```

So you now have this 'column' named `cnt`

```
$row = $db->fetch($res)
echo $row['cnt']
```